# Adding desired Ads in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, admob, iad

I am currently working on an app for iPhone which discourages smoking while portraying the hazards of smoking. I want to integrate ads in my app. During my research, i have come to know that iAds and Admobs are the two better choices. However, i want to display ads related to smoking (or smoking effects) only. How is it possible with any of these two? Is there any better alternative.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use content specific ads in any of the ad services for iOS. The ads come at random from the server of either of the ad networks. What you can do is put this question up to google or the specific service providers and see if they can give an appropriate solution. Most probably they would charge you for this .Its better you contact them using the following links

[Google Admob Support](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307260?hl=en)

Or I can offer you a workaround if you want to specifically show those ads related to smoking . Make your own ads using popups and other methods and then show them in your app. Here you can add your own url and hyperlink to the sites you want .

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

By doing some more search, i came up with this solution.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/search-ads-for-apps/